# Replicate Form in liferay portlet

Tags: jsp, liferay, liferay-ide, liferay-aui

I have a form in a jsp file. I want to add two buttons for adding/removing the form. Everytime the add button is pushed the same form is replicated below the original form. If I push the remove button the form is removed. I think there should be this function already implemented inside the liferay aui library.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, similar functionality available in Edit User screen for Address and Phone Numbers and other places too.

You can refer to phone_numbers.jsp and addresses.jsp at [location](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/tree/6.1.x/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/users_admin/common).

Comment: To which tag and part of the code you are referring in particular?